# How do I partition a drive using GParted ready for Ubuntu Server?

Tags: boot, partitioning, gparted, raid, raid5

I am using an 8 core PC with 4x 500GB drives to make a small storage server. It just for e-mails and files that should be deleted by the pack rats in the office won't let them go.

Originally, I was using Intel's BIOS fake raid and had it up and running with server 16.04. However, I removed a plug from the same power splitting block and cut power to it. It decided to totally break apt, etc. Thinking it was easier to nuke it and start again I am up to this point.

> Ubuntu 18.04 defaults to using a swap file instead of the previous method of having a dedicated swap partition.

Failing to get either 16.04 nor 18.04 to install with fake raid or soft raid, I thought I would throw in an additional old 80GB, make that the boot drive and use ZFS.

When the installation goes smoothly, the screen comes up with just a cursor. No message about, "No boot media". I have just had it run over night and using DD hopefully destroyed every byte of data on the drives to clear out any old boot information from previous attempts.

What I was originally trying to achieve was:

(Tried using an HTML tag or code block to display this nicely. >:[ )

Drive 1

- Raw = 5.5 GB /boot
- LVM / RAID5 = 10GB /
- RAID5 = Rest of GB /home

Drives 2-4

- Raw = 5.5GB swap
- LVM / RAID 5 = 10GB /
- RAID5 = Rest of GB /home

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working, using a very standard PC desktop partition configuration and Ubuntu 16.04. The cursor was a display driver problem. I had to route it through the VGA port using BIOS. Will be using ZFS for the RAID pool.

Having a proper server manual partition guide would still be nice and handy.

Edit:

This might help others: https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/advanced-installation.html.en-GB

... I guess that only I can help myself?